# Down votes without comments

Tags: feature-request, downvoting, down-votes

I’m not personally a great fan of the concept of down-votes, but I know people want to express a view and I understand they play a useful role. For me, the upvotes say enough and dreadful posts can be flagged for closure.

What I think is really unhelpful is when a question / answer receives down-votes with no feedback to the poster. Very few people intentionally post something unhelpful. What seems like a lousy post to an experienced user may not be so obvious to the novice. My personal mission is to try to get more people using Ubuntu and I think we risk putting people off by down-voting what they think is a reasonable question.

The tiny negative effect on your own reputation is not a deterrent to trigger-happy down-voting.

On the basis that everything we do in the site should make it better, would it be possible to mandate some kind of feedback to say *why* the post needs improvement when down-voting?

I don’t know if this is possible in SE, but I think it would be a very positive step. (I’m also interested in the irony of the number of down-votes my criticism of down-votes gets!!)

Comment: Related:  [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/902710) and [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/902710) (among others, I'm sure)

Comment: Thank you @NotTheDr01ds & muru - yes, answered very nicely there and I take all the points. Very annoying because I thought I’d searched before posting!

Comment: No worries.  Just curious - Did you search from the Stack Exchanges search tool or from a search engine?  I find just putting the word "Stack" in front of a Google query gives me (far, far) better results than the built-in search.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I searched using the built-in tool - good tip (re Google), thank you. I think the search I did gave several pages of results - I suspect the Q & A you referenced was there was buried in 15 pages of answers if I'd looked more carefully! Thanks again.